# sql functions not found after include

Tags: c++, mysql, c, macos

I've been working on a basic server/client program in c on a MacOSX, and when having tried to link the server to a mysql database, I'm having serious issues. I checked the sql header file and it had all the function declarations that the compiler cannot find. I downloaded a connector, specifically for the x86_64 architecture, and using it gave the same error.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <mysql/my_global.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

   //Create the connector object
   MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);
   if (con == NULL) {
     fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
     exit(1);
   }

   //Connect to database
   if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "username","password", NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) {
     fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
     mysql_close(con);
     exit(1);
   }
}
```

I get the following error upon compiling it:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "_finish_with_error", referenced from:
   _main in ServerSocket-dbb1df.o
   "_mysql_close", referenced from:
   _main in ServerSocket-dbb1df.o
   "_mysql_error", referenced from:
   _main in ServerSocket-dbb1df.o
   "_mysql_init", referenced from:
   _main in ServerSocket-dbb1df.o
   "_mysql_query", referenced from:
   _main in ServerSocket-dbb1df.o
   "_mysql_real_connect", referenced from:
   _main in ServerSocket-dbb1df.o
   "_mysql_store_result", referenced from:
   _main in ServerSocket-dbb1df.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help as to what's going wrong here would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using precompiled headers?

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes I am using precompiled headers

Comment: @Cris Luengo I'm sure from where I can link the library to the headers. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If you are using precompiled headers, you should have included "stdafx.h". Please show where you do that. (I assume you left out that line to make your code example more minimal.) Inlcuding it should be the very first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message "ld: symbol(s) not found" indicates you're not linking a library into your program.

The MySQL documentation, and specifically [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api-building-clients.html), explains how to link your program with the MySQL library:

> `mysql_config` displays the options needed for compiling or linking:
>
> ```
> shell> mysql_config --cflags
> shell> mysql_config --libs
> ```
>
> You can run those commands to get the proper options and add them manually to compilation or link commands. Alternatively, include the output from `mysql_config` directly within command lines using backticks:
>
> ```
> shell> gcc -c `mysql_config --cflags` progname.c
> shell> gcc -o progname progname.o `mysql_config --libs`
> ```

If you use C++ (you have both C and C++ as tags in your question) you'll want to replace `gcc` with `g++` of course, but also replace `--cflags` with `--cxxflags`.

Comment: This fixed my problem. +1 for concise and simple answer

Comment: Since, in my case, the flags were already included with the sql header, gcc -o program progame.c  `mysql_config --libs` did the job for me. Just an alternative